# C# Memory Leak on Uploading Images?

Tags: c#

I have this code which I use with a Xamarin app. But I thought this is the better place to ask because it's more of a C# question. I have an app where you take photos and they get added to a list and uploaded to the server. The code below is what is used to upload the images, theres a timer that runs each 5 seconds to send an image to the server (once it gets an OK response, which is does everytime) it removes the image from the list, am I missing something obvious on to why after excessive use of the app it crashes?

```
public App()
        {
            DB = new DataAccess(URL);
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Landing()) { BarTextColor = Color.White };
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
            {
                if (imagesToUpload.Count != 0)
                {
                CallFileToServer();
            }
            return true; 
        });
    }

    private async void CallFileToServer()
    {
        await SendFileToServer(imagesToUpload.FirstOrDefault().imageBytes, imagesToUpload.FirstOrDefault().shipmentNum);
    }

    private async Task SendFileToServer(byte[] image, string shipmentNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri webService = new Uri(URL + "imageUpload/" + shipmentNumber);
            using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
            {
                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("----MyGreatBoundary"))
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(image))
                    {
                        content.Add(new StreamContent(memoryStream), "file", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg");
                        using (var message = await client.PostAsync(webService, content))
                        {
                            string response = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            if (message.ReasonPhrase.ToLower() == "OK".ToLower())
                            {
                                imagesToUpload.Remove(imagesToUpload.FirstOrDefault(f => f.imageBytes == image));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is the adding the image to the list code, however I've asked a similar question beforehand and I've been told this most likely isn't the issue.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    App.imagesToUpload.Add(new ImageToUpload
                    {
                        imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray(),
                        shipmentNum = Result.ToString(),
                        imageData = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path)
                    });
                    tempCollection.Add(new TempImage
                    {
                        imgSource = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path)
                    });
                    file.Dispose();
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                }
```

TempCollection is cleared once the form is submitted so that list isn't the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the top block of code your current code? Or the bottom one?

Comment: Define "crashes."

Comment: Side note, it is poor practice to new up an HttpClient for every request.  You'll want to change that.  See [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: One immediately apparent potential cause is that you do `new MemoryStream(image)` outside of a using statement. Its possible that `StreamContent` which it is passed to will dispose of it but I have no evidence to that effect... Out of curiosity did you actually look at where you were creating memory streams when trying to diagnose your memory problems?

Comment: Also an apparent potential cause is the `file.GetStream().CopyTo(..)` which is used outside of a `using` statement.
Also, you don't have to manually call `Dispose` on variables inside a `using` statement (i.e. the `memoryStream` variable).

Comment: @mjwills Both blocks of code are being used at the moment, the top one is used to upload the photos and the bottom one is used to add the photos to the list.

Comment: @CareyGregory An exception is being thrown, however Xamarin debugger on this specific project is broken and I've had no luck with running it (so I'm forced to run it in release) and it's a hard crash to replicate because I literally have to take over 150 images for it to happen.

Comment: Have considered to simply use a memory profiler to identify cause for the leak? ("dotMemory" from JetBrains is great profiler for example, but IIRC there are also free alternatives out there)

Comment: @Chris I've not done much work with MemoryStreams before, this is the first internal app I've created with uploading images and handling large byte arrays. I was under the impression that the memory stream would dispose of itself because it's in the using, am I incorrect?

Comment: @bassfader Thanks for the suggestion. There is a profiler for Xamarin, however you need to be a Visual Studio Enterprise member and I don't have a license at the moment so I need to find a workaround without :(

Comment: @martennis Thanks I will remove the dispose on the memory stream! but there is a sample project for taking picture via Xamarin and there example they use file.GetStream its the only way to retrieve the byte[] from the "MediaFile" class which is returned from taking the photo. I think as long as I dispose of file I'm ok on that part.

Comment: @SeanDavies: You are using various memory streams at the moment. The one I am referring to is content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(image)).... While this is in the scope of another using you are not "using" this particular memory stream so no, it won't get disposed of correctly. I assume you're thinking it would get disposed of because you were thinking of a different use such as using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) - in this case it would get disposed of. If you still don't understand what I'm saying go read the docs for using again.

Comment: @Chris Thanks!, I implemented the using for the MemoryStream and did a test but looks like I'm getting the same results :( Or would I need to do the same thing for the StreamContent too? I've updated the main question with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're instantiating a new HttpClient each time you're uploading a file.
Although the HttpClient is disposable, you should re-use a single HttpClient instance as much as you can.
See [this](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) article for more information.

I don't know if this is the reason of your problem since you're vague on the exact problem that arises, but you might give it a shot.